# WSL2, Docker & Node : Unable to request Node

Tags: node.js, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a JS app with Docker Compose with a front, a back and a common component with Yarn Workspaces. It works on Linux. I am out of ideas to make it work on WSL.

The Docker Compose :

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    # restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: caddie_app
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  backend:
    image: node:16
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - '3001:3001' # Nest
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    working_dir: /app
    command: ["yarn", "workspace", "@caddie/backend", "start:dev"]
    environment:
      # with docker we listen to the postgres network, but it is reachable at @localhost on our post
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:password@postgres:5432/caddie_app?schema=public

  frontend:
    image: node:16
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000' # React
    depends_on:
      - backend
    working_dir: /app
    command: ["yarn", "workspace", "@caddie/frontend", "start"]
```

I can reach the database with DBeaver, I can fetch the React JS scripts on localhost:3000, but I cannot request the NestJS server on localhost:3001.

The NestJS server is listening on 0.0.0.0

```
await app.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0');
```

I allowed the ports 3000 & 3001 on the Firewall. I tried to request directly the NodeJS through the IP of WSL found in ipconfig but the problem remains. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks !

Comment: from where are you trying to access this? Localhost should work just fine, if this is your workbox.

Comment: I am trying to access it from my browser. I am not trying anything fancy. I can't reach the node server and everything's working on my Linux work computer.

Comment: I mean are you trying to access to from the same machine this is running on?

Comment: Yes. I start WSL and run docker-compose up. I am on the same computer.

Comment: well it should work. there is nothing really different from the way you run it on regular linux. You also can see this with postgres and react, which you can access just fine. Do you have anything in the container logs?

Comment: No logs, I can't even hit the container. On my browser or Postman I have "Error: socket hang up", which I believe is when the server never sent a response

Comment: You sure the container is running? What do you mean you can't even hit the container?

Comment: Yes I am sure the container is working. This is all working fine on a Linux computer, but the node server is not working on a Windows computer with WSL. No clue why

Comment: if you dont have any logs, maybe its  not running properly. How about adding some logs statement to follow what your server is doing? Well, as it stands, this needs more debugging details. If 2 out of 3 containers are working, it doesn't appear to be an issue with your setup, but a specific problem with that container. Perhaps you forgot something.

Comment: The server and the container are started correctly. NestJS says it is, it's working fine on Linux. However, I cannot reach it with a request on Windows.